# Prove that biconditional cannot be expressed in terms of implication alone.

Tags: logic

Is it sufficient to show that since $A \Leftrightarrow  B$ is equivalent to $(A \Rightarrow B) \land (B \Rightarrow A)$ and as conjunction cannot be expressed using conditional alone, neither can biconditional? I can't think of a convincing argument why this would hold. Maybe with some rearrangement it would still be possible?

I tried to get a contradiction using induction like [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48258/604526) but could not find any.

Comment: The suggested proof wouldn't be enough. In general, we have to be careful when proving the negative of something: it's not enough to say "this is an approach to proving the positive statement, but that approach won't work"—even if true, conceivably some other approach might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write an expression just involving propositional variables and the connective
$\implies$ focus on the right-most variable, $X$ say. If that takes the value $T$ (true) then
the whole expression takes the value $T$. So the expression cannot be logically equivalent
to $A\iff B$ since if $A$ and $B$ take distinct values the expression must evaluate
to $F$ (false). If $A$ is $X$ then taking $A=T$ and $B=F$ gives a contradiction; likewise
if $B$ is $X$. If neither $A$ nor $B$ is $X$, again take $A=T$ and $B=F$ and $X=T$
to give a contradiction.

Comment: Wow, that is a MUCH slicker argument than mine, haha. Nice! ^_^